# When i modify a variable that depends of my parent state i dont want that modify the initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, state

I'm trying to set a filter, so, what i'm doing is first creating a new variable called filteredDataParentSate which is the total state of my principal class, inside i have the data(array of objects) that i want to filter, i use .filter function to generate the filtered array, i set this filtered data on my previos variable filteredDataParentSate. i pass the total filteredDataParentSate to my component which show the data.

The filter works fine when i write the input, the problem is that i don't know why the parentState also modify, so when i delete the input the data didn't return to the original state.

```
render() {
    let filteredDataParentSate = this.props.parentState
    let filterdData = filteredDataParentSate.data.filter(
      (dat) =>{
        return dat.nombre_completo.toLowerCase().indexOf(filteredDataParentSate.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      }
    )
    console.log(this.props.parentState.data) 
    filteredDataParentSate.data = filterdData
    console.log(this.props.parentState.data)//this have to return the same that the previous console.log, but this return the filtered data
```

Here i send the data to the component that show it

```
<TableNotTableRender
            parentState={filteredDataParentSate}
            methods={{
              handleshow: this.handleshow,
              addRecaudo: this.addRecaudo,
              deletetransaction: this.deletetransaction,
              cancelTransaction: this.props.methods.cancelTransaction,
              prealistadoButton: this.props.methods.prealistadoButton,
              showProducts: this.props.methods.showProducts,
              isDelivered: this.props.methods.isDelivered,
              sort: this.props.methods.sort,
              updateSearch: this.props.methods.updateSearch
            }}
          >
```

and in my parentstate this is my state:

```
class ListarClientes extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            globalTitle: "Clientes",
            addedProductos: [],
            id_usuario: "",
            productsPrice: "",
            totalPrice: "",
            rebatePrice: "",
            shippingPrice: "",
            data: [],// 
            indexSort: "",
            orderSort: "",
            search: "",
```

the data in my state fills with a get call, this is the data to filter, normally is something like this:

```
"data": [
    {
      "id_usuario": "18",
      "nombre_completo": "Nuevo cliente",
      "tipo_identificacion": "CC",
      "identificacion": "103855555",
      "celular": "20202020",
      "fk_ciudad": "1",
      "fk_departamento": "52",
      "correo": "nuevo.cliente@nuevo.com",
      "direccion": "calle 82a # 70-78",
      "estrato": "3",
      "canal_adquisicion": "Referida",
      "fecha_nacimiento": "1994-12-10",
      "fk_id_usuario": "15",
      "fk_id_campana": null,
      "edad": 32,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-26T02:33:46.223Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-26T21:47:43.196Z",
  },
    {
      "id_usuario": "15",
      "nombre_completo": "Otro Cliente",
      "tipo_identificacion": "CC",
      "identificacion": "1038444444",
      "celular": "3190000000",
      "fk_ciudad": "1",
      "fk_departamento": "1",
      "correo": "otro@otro.com",
      "direccion": "calle 82a",
      "estrato": "3",
      "canal_adquisicion": "Referida",
      "fecha_nacimiento": "1996-01-16",
      "fk_id_usuario": "13",
      "fk_id_campana": null,
      "edad": 24,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-22T02:31:52.254Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-28T20:52:03.010Z",
    },
]
```

this is my method that update the search input

```
    updateSearch = (event) => {
        this.setState({ search: event.target.value })
    }
```

Comment: How are you setting the state from the Parent Component? Non-primitive data types like Arrays and Objects are passed by reference. So both these references might be pointing to the same object in the memory. Please share more code so that it can be confirmed.

Comment: Thanks, i already add more code.